# A number theoretical identity of exponential sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, goldbach-type-problems

I try to understand a number theoretical identity used by
Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161947/what-keeps-asymptotic-goldbachs-conjecture-out-of-reach-of-current-technology/162085#162085).

He defined the function

$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n) e(n\alpha)$$

where $\Lambda(n)$ is the
[Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) and $e(x)$ the exponential $e(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$.

Assume $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}$ is rational, and $p:= p_1 p_2...p_n$ and
$q:= q_1 ...p_m$ are *coprime* positive integers where $p_i$ and
$q_j$ are primes such that every pair $p_i, q_j$ is pair wise different.

Why the following identity is true:

$$\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n) e(n\alpha) = 
\sum_{(a,q)=1} e(\frac{ap}{q})\underset{n\equiv a\pmod{q}}{\sum_{n\leq N}} \Lambda(n)$$

Comment: It should follow from grouping the sum over $n\leq N$ into residue classes mod $q,$ and for each residue class representative $a$ and just use the geometric series applied to the sum of the Fourier coefficients

Comment: so I guess I am wondering what exactly broke down in this approach (if you tried it)? otherwise worth trying it.

Comment: @kodlu: 
Thank you I tried to apply your approach but 
there is a problem. We grouping them as you suggested

$\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n) e(n\alpha) =
\sum_{j=1}^q  
\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}: \ j+l \cdot q \leq N}^{l_{j,N}} 
\Lambda(j+l \cdot q) \cdot e(\alpha(j+l \cdot q))$

Comment: Now $e(a+b)= e(a)a(b)$ and since $\alpha =p/q$, 
$e(\alpha \cdot q \cdot l) =1$, so
$e(\alpha(j+l \cdot q))= e(\alpha \cdot j)$. Thus
$$...= \sum_{j=1}^q e(\alpha \cdot j) 
 \sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}: \ j+l \cdot q \leq N}^{l_{j,N}}
\Lambda(j+l \cdot q)$$

Comment: That looks that we are almost done, but now how 
get rid of the $j \in {1,2,..., q}$ in the
first sum with $(j,q) \neq 1$?

Comment: $\sum_{n \leqslant N} \Lambda(n) e(n \alpha)=\sum_{n \leqslant N,n \equiv a(\bmod q)} e\left(\frac{a p \alpha}{q}\right) \Lambda(n)=\sum_{(a,q)=1} e\left(\frac{a p \alpha}{q}\right) \sum_{n \leqslant N,n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \Lambda(n)$

Comment: I can't see where Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta has  taken $(a,q)=1$. And get an extra term $$\sum_{q_i} \log(q_i)(\sum_{r=1}^{b_i: {q_i \leq N}^{b_i}} e({q_i}^{r}\alpha))$$ to be added to the r.h.s of your asked identity. And this extra term isn't zero.

Comment: Alapan Das: $\alpha$ is a rational number, so... Btw the previous comment of mine should drop $\alpha$ in $e\left(\frac{a p \alpha}{q}\right)$. Btw when $q|a, e(\frac{ap}{q})=0$.

Comment: @Katago How can an exponential be $0$?

Comment: $e(\frac{ap}{q})=e^{2\pi i\frac{ap}{q}}$, sorry, be 1. and then $\sum_{q^k\leq N}\Lambda( q^k)=\log_q N\log q=\log N$ is a minor term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n \leq N} e(n\alpha) \Lambda(n) =\left(\sum_{p \leq N} \log(p) \sum_{r=1}^{a(p): p^{a(p)} \leq N} e(p^r\alpha)\right)$$

But, the right hand side is gives,
$$\left(\sum_{(a,q)=1 ,a<q} e(a\frac{p}{q})\sum_{\substack{n \leq N \\ n \equiv a (\text{modulo q})}} \Lambda(n) \right)=\sum_{\substack{p \leq N \\ p \nmid q}} \log(p) \sum_{r=0}^{a(p): p^{a(p)} \leq N} e(p^r\alpha)$$.

[ This is because $q_i \nmid n, \text{where} n \equiv a (\text{modulo q}), (a,q)=1$ ].

$$\chi(q)=\sum_{\substack q_i} \log(q_i) \sum_{r=0}^{b_i: {q_i}^{b_i} \leq N} e({q_i}^r\alpha)$$.

($q_i$ s are prime factors of $q$)

This, $\chi(q)$ obviously depends on the $N$ and isn't zero generally.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more extensive why the identity 
$$\left(\sum_{(a,q)=1 ,a<q} e(a\frac{p}{q})\sum_{\substack{n \leq N \\ n \equiv a (\text{modulo q})}} \Lambda(n) \right)=\sum_{\substack{p \leq N \\ p \nmid q}} \log(p) \sum_{r=0}^{a(p): p^{a(p)} \leq N} e(p^r\alpha)$$.

is true. I not understand.

Comment: Because the Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)=log(p),$ when $n=p^{a} \rightarrow \text{perfect power of some primes}$. Now, $n$ can't be any power of the primes $q_i$ as these divides $q$, but doesn't divide $a$ as $(a,q)=1$. For $n$ which isn't a perfect power of prime Mangoldt function is zero.